# Validating all inputs field of only visible tabs jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Hy,
I have a form divided in 4 tabs, 3 of wich are always visible and 1 only shows on certain conditions. I have a save button and when the user clicks on it I need to validate the data in all visible form. the problem is that when the fourth tab is hidden it's included in the validation process. 
this is my call do jquery validate

```
   $('#frmEdit_SociBDP').validate({ignore:"ui-tabs-hide",
    invalidHandler: function(e, validator){
    if(validator.errorList.length)
        $('#tabs a[href="#' + jQuery(validator.errorList[0].element).closest(".tab-   pane").attr('id') + '"]').tab('show');
    }});
```

I don't know if there is a different string to pass to ignore so to ignore the hidden tabs, or maybe there is some other workaround i.e. removing the required class from the fields that mustn't be validated, 
anyone has some ideas?
thank's

**EDIT:** HERE'S part of my form html code

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs" style="width:900px">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-AnagraficaBase" data-toggle="tab">Anagrafica base</a></li>
        <li id="completa" style=""><a href="#tab-AnagraficaCompleta" data-toggle="tab">Anagrafica completa</a></li>
        <li id="attachments" style=""><a href="#tab-Allegati" data-toggle="tab">Allegati</a></li>
        <li id="info" style="display: none;"><a href="#tab-Aziende" data-toggle="tab">Info Azienda</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and this are the tab contents divs

```
<div id="tab-AnagraficaBase">//many inputs</div>
<div id="tab-AnagraficaCompleta">//many inputs</div>
<div id="tab-Aziende">//many inputs</div>
<div id="tab-Allegati">//other inputs</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your ignore selector is the problem.

You can safely remove the property since the default configuration ignores hidden elements from validation- default options `ignore: ":hidden"`.

---

Your selector `ui-tabs-hide` seems to be wrong as it looks like a class, but you are using it as a element selector instead of class selector.

Try instead

```
ignore:".ui-tabs-hide :input"
```

Comment: I tried removing the ingore but at that point only the input of the active tab gets validate, I then tried with ignore: '.ui-tabs-hide :input' but nothing changed

Comment: then how do you separate the hidden tab... is there any other attribute assigned to it

Comment: Solved adding to the div the ui-tabs-hide class